# Rabbitmq - how to listen to messages on an exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I have a program in Java that sends messages to RabbitMQ. All I know is the exchange name. No queues, bindings, and so on.

My question is this: how can I see if the program sends these successfully, knowing only the exchange name?

Thanks.

Regards,
Serban

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable [publisher confirmation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) with RabbitMQ. It's like having a send-transaction, where RabbitMQ will tell you whether or not the message was sent successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Please look here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html

```java
String queueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
channel.queueBind(queueName, "EXCHANGE_NAME", "");

System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");
Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
  @Override
  public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, 
                             Envelope envelope,
                             AMQP.BasicProperties properties, 
                             byte[] body) throws IOException 
{
    String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
  }
};
channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);
```

In a few words, you have to:

1. create a queue, in this case anonymous queue
2. bind the queue to your exchange

It is important to know what kind of the `exchange` you have since the binding can change, between `fanout` or `topic` or `direct`

In this example is `fanout`

Answer (score 0):

Assume that we have RabbitMQ Exchange we need to create an queue to push the message to the exchange and consume it from the queue as following

```
    private static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "2022";
    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "2022";
    private final static boolean durable = true;

// now we need to create a connection to rabbitmq server //

        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setUsername("guest");
        factory.setPassword("guest");
        factory.setVirtualHost("/");
        factory.setHost("127.0.0.1");
        factory.setPort(5672);
        Connection conn = factory.newConnection();
       // create rabbitmq connection chaneel        
       Channel channel = conn.createChannel();
      //Declare Exchange // 
      channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "topic", true);
     // push message to rabbitmq exchange 

channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, "routingkey", null, yourmessage.getBytes());
```

the above work as producer now we need to create queue consumer

```
    private static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "2022";
    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "2022";
    private final static boolean durable = true;

// now we need to create a connection to rabbitmq server //

        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setUsername("guest");
        factory.setPassword("guest");
        factory.setVirtualHost("/");
        factory.setHost("127.0.0.1");
        factory.setPort(5672);
        Connection conn = factory.newConnection();
        // create rabbitmq connection chaneel       
        Channel channel = conn.createChannel();


          channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "topic", true);

          //Queue Declare //
          channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
         //Queue bind //
        channel.queueBind(QUEUE_NAME, EXCHANGE_NAME, "routingkey");
        // Queue Consume // 
        QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);

  while (true)
        {
            QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
            String message = new String(delivery.getBody());

            System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");


        }
```